# Is it possible to create a nuclear reactor the size of a melon?

Tags: nuclear-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the minimum amount of fissile mass required to acheive criticality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13325/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-fissile-mass-required-to-acheive-criticality)

I want to make a red laser the only problem is that the power is not sufficient so I had to resort to a nuclear reactor.

Comment: Answer is yes: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13325/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-fissile-mass-required-to-acheive-criticality and I can't say anything about the laser part without being insulting.  Maybe you should google "thorium maxfelaser" or "thorium powered car".

Comment: In its current form, I don't think this question separates itself from the linked one, so I'm going to close it as a duplicate. If this gets edited for quality and to show how it's distinct from the other question, it could be reopened.